# Error with using AsyncTask and Service with AlarmManager

Tags: service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a problem when using AsyncTask on Service. It can not run again after restart the phone.

My app need always run on background get GPS (from phone) and send to my server.

I use an AlarmManager to setRepeat function X.

- Function X include :

  - task A: get data (GPS).
  - task B: use network connection to post data to my server.
  - task B only starts after when task A finished.

I use OnBootReceiver to set up it run on Background and always work.

**My first workflow is:**

1. OnBootReceiver calls Service.
2. Service calls AlarmManager.
3. AlarmManager after interval x miniutes will call function X.
4. Function X have an AsyncTask
5. Some code of Func X:

   AsyncTask mAsyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
               getLocation(context, "gps.db");
           }

   ```
       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {             
           postLocation(context, "gps.db");                
           return null;
       }   
   };
   mAsyncTask.execute(null, null, null);
   ```

**The second workflow is:**

1. OnBootReceiver calls AlarmManager.
2. After interval, AlarmManager will create a Service.
3. Service will call function X.
4. Function X have an AsyncTask

**I must use AsyncTask and the Post function is in onRunInBackground because android will kill my app if the app run after a long time.**

**- getData must run on UI thread.**

**- postData mustn't run on UI thread.**

**PLEASE GIVE ME A ADVICE**

Answer (score 0):

The [Training for Android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) states:

> By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To prevent this from happening, you can design your application to automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the device. This ensures that the AlarmManager will continue doing its task without the user needing to manually restart the alarm.

Have you done this?